# java collatz code not stop when reach 1

Tags: java, jvm, collatz

I created this collatz code, when I run the command 'java collatz 7', my program doesn't terminate when n reaches 1, instead it keeps repeating the sequence until the StackOverflowError. Could anyone point out what is the issue here? Thx

```
public class collatz{
    public static void collatz(int n){
            System.out.println(n+" ");
            if(n==1)
                    return;
            if(n%2==0)
                    collatz(n/2);
            collatz(n*3+1);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
            collatz(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the problem:

```
        if(n%2==0)
            collatz(n/2);
        collatz(n*3+1);
```

If `n%2==0` it will call BOTH of those.  I think it should instead be this:

```
        if(n%2==0)
            collatz(n/2);
        else
            collatz(n*3+1);
```

Now it will only call it once.